# std::conditional параметр в конструкторе

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы

Пытаюсь написать класс, реализующий одновременно константный и неконстантый итератор как показано [здесь](http://www.sj-vs.net/c-implementing-const_iterator-and-non-const-iterator-without-code-duplication/).

Проблема возникает при компиляции следующего участка кода(упрощено):

```
class SimpleIt {
    using my_vector_ref_type = named_vector<T>&;
public:
    SimpleIt(my_vector_ref_type r) {}
};

//То же самое, но с std::conditional
template <bool is_const>
class CondIt {
    using my_vector_ref_type = std::conditional<
            is_const,
            const named_vector<T>&,
            named_vector<T>&
    >;
public:
    CondIt(my_vector_ref_type r) {}
};

iterator begin() {
    SimpleIt si(*this); //Компилирует
    CondIt<false> c(*this); //error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'CondIt<false>'
```

PS: http://tpcg.io/FBny1V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых нужен `#include <type_traits>`, во вторых нужно имя типа:

```
using my_vector_ref_type = typename ::std::conditional
<
        is_const
,       const named_vector<T>&
,       named_vector<T>&
>::type;
```

А если используется с++14, то можно написать короче:

```
using my_vector_ref_type = ::std::conditional_t
<
        is_const
,       const named_vector<T>&
,       named_vector<T>&
>;
```

Comment: фууух, у меня бомбило уже, спасибо